# xsl:fo inline line wrap and line break

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm struggling with my xsl:fo (Apache Fop 1.1). 
I'm trying to generate a Block with inline images and inline text elements which might contain newline characters.

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:inline>First Line&#10;Second Line, Image: </fo:inline>
    <fo:inline>
        <fo:external-graphic scaling="non-uniform" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="4mm" height="4mm" src="data:image;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGcAAABfCAIAAAB6Ck5uAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAA0SURBVHhe7cGBAAAAAMOg+VNf4QBVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHCoAXMKAAFau+l4AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"/>
    </fo:inline>
    <fo:inline> some more Text on Line 2&#10;3rd Line</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

I expect the output would be

```
FirstLine
SecondLine, Image: || some more Text on Line 2
3rd Line
```

what I get is:

```
FirstLine SecondLine, Image: || some more Text on Line 2 3rd Line
```

I've been playing a while now with the following attributes on the fo:block element and/or the fo:inline elements giving strange or unexpected results.

```
white-space-collapse="false" 
white-space-treatment="preserve" 
linefeed-treatment="preserve"
```

Any suggestions?

Edit 1:
Changing the inline elements into blocks like this

```
<fo:block white-space-treatment="ignore">
    <fo:block white-space="pre">First Line&#xA;Second Line, Image: </fo:block>
    <fo:block>
        <fo:external-graphic scaling="non-uniform" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="4mm" height="4mm" src="data:image;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGcAAABfCAIAAAB6Ck5uAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAA0SURBVHhe7cGBAAAAAMOg+VNf4QBVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHCoAXMKAAFau+l4AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"/>
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block white-space="pre"> some more Text on Line 2&#10;3rd Line</fo:block>
</fo:block>
```

gives me the expected wrapping within the elements, but a new line is generated for each block which isn't what I'm trying to archive.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Linefeeds can be present in an FO document as linefeed characters or numeric character entities (`&#x000A;` or `&#10;`); the following FO blocks are completely equivalent:

```
<fo:block>Before the linefeed&#x000A;after the linefeed.</fo:block>

<fo:block>Before the linefeed
after the linefeed.</fo:block>
```

The default handling of linefeeds consists in:

1. **converting** them into normal spaces;
2. **collapsing** them with other adjacent spaces.

*This explains why your initial input produces an output where all the content pieces are placed consecutively on the same line.*

Using the property `linefeed-treatment="preserve"` both forms of linefeeds are retained, and the [line building process](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#area-linebuild) will respect them (they are called forced line-breaks). Note that **`linefeed-treatment` only applies to `fo:block` elements**; it has no effect on `fo:inline` elements.

*Your "edit 1" block has more linefeeds than you need because "... Second Line, Image: ", the image and "some more Text on Line 2 ..." are inside three different `fo:block` elements, and each block generates its own lines.*

### Solution 1:

The simplest way to get your desired output is probably this one, with a single `fo:block` having its linefeed preserved (this is just your original input, after removing the unnecessary `fo:inline`s and putting everything on the same line:

```
<fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">First Line&#xA;Second Line, Image: <fo:external-graphic scaling="non-uniform" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="4mm" height="4mm" src="data:image;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGcAAABfCAIAAAB6Ck5uAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAA0SURBVHhe7cGBAAAAAMOg+VNf4QBVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHCoAXMKAAFau+l4AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"/> some more Text on Line 2&#10;3rd Line</fo:block>
```

Note that **you cannot indent this code**, because the extra linefeeds would appear in the output too!

### Solution 2:

A second solution, which doesn't involve using the `linefeed-treatment` property and creates more easily readable code, would be to use **empty blocks** instead of forced linefeeds:

```
<fo:block>
    First Line<fo:block/>Second Line, Image: 
    <fo:external-graphic scaling="non-uniform" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="4mm" height="4mm" src="data:image;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGcAAABfCAIAAAB6Ck5uAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAA0SURBVHhe7cGBAAAAAMOg+VNf4QBVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHCoAXMKAAFau+l4AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"/> 
    some more Text on Line 2<fo:block/>3rd Line
</fo:block>
```

As linefeeds are not preserved, we can use them freely:

```
<fo:block>
    First Line
    <fo:block/>
    Second Line, Image: 
    <fo:external-graphic scaling="non-uniform" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="4mm" height="4mm" src="data:image;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGcAAABfCAIAAAB6Ck5uAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAA0SURBVHhe7cGBAAAAAMOg+VNf4QBVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHCoAXMKAAFau+l4AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"/> 
    some more Text on Line 2
    <fo:block/>
    3rd Line
</fo:block>
```

The empty blocks partition the content of the outer block without creating anything in the output.

Comment: How would I preserve the blank spaces at the end of the 1st inline and the beginning of the 3rd inline when using Solution 2?

Comment: @kai Do you mean the spaces immediately before and after the image? As per the default whitespace / linefeed handling, the linefeed character becomes a space, and collapses with the surrounding space characters to form a single space, so the output has: `Second Line, Image:<space><image><space>some more Text on Line 2`. The other spaces, being at the beginning  or at the end of a "paragraph" are ignored.

Answer (score 4):

Just found the answer in the comments of [FOP 1536](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-1536?focusedCommentId=13521766&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13521766).

Now I'm using

```
linefeed-treatment="preserve"
```

on the block element and I'm replacing all spaces within the text inlines with some unicode magic in the xsl before:

```
replace(@text, ' ', '&#x00A0;&#x200B;')
```

Edit 1:
To be a bit more precise, this is the relevant part of the xsl I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ 
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
    <!ENTITY ZeroWidthSpace "&#x200B;"> 
]>

<fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
    <fo:inline><xsl:value-of select="replace(@text, ' ', '&nbsp;&ZeroWidthSpace;')"/></fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

With this approach I'm getting a pretty clean indented xml while having full control over linebreaks and blank spaces.